# Disable Visual Studio addin option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am developing Visual studio plugin . I am populating visual studio add in option in `OnConnection()` method of `Connect.cs` class.

Now I want to disable the add in option, based on the opened `host` project.

For example, I want add in option enable if `web project` is open. otherwise it should be disabled.

In which `event` of `connect.cs` class I can achieve this and how ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
    _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(openedSolution);
    _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents.AfterClosing += new _dispSolutionEvents_AfterClosingEventHandler(closedSolution);
```

"Internal" refference in the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/EnvDTE.aspx

You can determine the type of the project with this code (from http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007016.aspx):

```
public string GetProjectTypeGuids(EnvDTE.Project proj)
    {

        string projectTypeGuids = "";
        object service = null;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution solution = null;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy hierarchy = null;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject aggregatableProject = null;
        int result = 0;

        service = GetService(proj.DTE, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution));
        solution = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution)service;

        result = solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(proj.UniqueName, hierarchy);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            aggregatableProject = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject)hierarchy;
            result = aggregatableProject.GetAggregateProjectTypeGuids(projectTypeGuids);
        }

        return projectTypeGuids;

    }

    public object GetService(object serviceProvider, System.Type type)
    {
        return GetService(serviceProvider, type.GUID);
    }

    public object GetService(object serviceProviderObject, System.Guid guid)
    {

        object service = null;
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
        IntPtr serviceIntPtr;
        int hr = 0;
        Guid SIDGuid;
        Guid IIDGuid;

        SIDGuid = guid;
        IIDGuid = SIDGuid;
        serviceProvider = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)serviceProviderObject;
        hr = serviceProvider.QueryService(SIDGuid, IIDGuid, serviceIntPtr);

        if (hr != 0)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        else if (!serviceIntPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            service = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(serviceIntPtr);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Release(serviceIntPtr);
        }

        return service;
    }
```

You find a list of known GUIDs [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)

To disable your option you would remove or add the menuentry regarding on the Type (check for GUID) in the `openedSolution` method

Comment: Zumbe: how to disable option ?

Comment: I have tried subscribing to this _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(openedSolution); event. But when I open host solution its is not firing.

Comment: My event worked. solution to this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405167/dte2-events-dont-fire)